# how to make cron job every day at 6 O'clock by Cpanel

Tags: php, cron

how to make cron job every day at 6 O'clock  by Cpanel  ?
I added cron job by my cpanel  as this picture

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5esAq.jpg

But the script work more one time in the day , I need to know the error in cron or in my script .

Comment: i found this [cron calculator](http://www.csgnetwork.com/crongen.html) :p

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your cron will run every minute at 6 o'clock, because of that asterisk.

[Cron format](http://www.nncron.ru/help/EN/working/cron-format.htm):

```
* * * * * *
| | | | | | 
| | | | | +-- Year              (range: 1900-3000)
| | | | +---- Day of the Week   (range: 1-7, 1 standing for Monday)
| | | +------ Month of the Year (range: 1-12)
| | +-------- Day of the Month  (range: 1-31)
| +---------- Hour              (range: 0-23)
+------------ Minute            (range: 0-59)
Any of these 6 fields may be an asterisk (*). 
This would mean the entire range of possible values, i.e. each minute, each hour, etc.
```

You should put minute 0 because you need to run it just once (at 06:00).

```
0 6 * * *
```

Comment: Just to clarify "because it will run every minute at 6 o'clock":

You should put a minute 0 that way it will run *once* at 6 o'clock instead of every minute on the 6th hour:

(i.e. 6:00, 6:01, 6:02...etc)

Comment: Thanks @jp093121, clarified. I really do appreciate your suggestion. My one line answer needed a much better explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your cronjob like following:

`0 6 * * *  /usr/bin/php and so on`

In this way it will run at 6 o'clock. In your way, it will start running at 6 and then it will run again every minute for an hour.

As example, if you want a script to run on the 3rd day of the month at midnight, you should write:

`0 0 3 * * /usr/bin/php and so on`

If you leave asterisk on the first two field, it will run for the whole day.

Have a look to the [man page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/5/crontab/). Some example can be very useful, i.e. the one with `@daily` macro.